# How to pass variable type as an argument to an function in IEC61131-3 structured text (TwinCAT3)?

Tags: plc, twincat, st, structured-text, iec61131-3

This is what I would like to have (this is a constructor for FB object):

```
METHOD FB_init : BOOL
    VAR_INPUT
        bInitRetains : BOOL;
        bInCopyCode : BOOL;

        //My variables:
        typeOfVariable : TYPE; // This obviously doesn't work 
    END_VAR

size := 1;
myArray := __NEW(typeOfVariable, size); // Create dynamic array with 'typeOfVariable' variables.

END_METHOD
```

- In this method I would pass to the parameter `typeOfVariable` for
  example `REAL` and the method would create array of `REAL` variables with
  size `1`.
- I need to know what `type` I declare `typeOfVariable` so it can store the
  data about `type` of another variable.

---

- Working example is the `__NEW()` method for dynamically creating array.
- This method takes in a argument such as `REAL` or `INT`.

This is the code for it:

```
myArray := __NEW(REAL, 10); //Create array with type REAL variables with the size of 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here a small example how you could tackle this problem:

Create an Enum first:

```
TYPE E_Type :
(
    eNO_TYPE := 0,
    eINT,
    eREAL
);
END_TYPE
```

Use it in a switch case:

```
METHOD createArray : POINTER TO BYTE
VAR_INPUT
    eType : E_Type;
    size : UINT;
END_VAR

CASE eType OF
    eINT:
        //Remember to __DELETE
        createArray := __NEW(INT, size);
    eREAL:
        createArray := __NEW(REAL, size);
END_CASE
```

Check for Null-Pointer and remember to __Delete when you don't need the array anymore.

Comment: this is actually implementation I am using now. But I am still curios if there is another way to do it - therefor I put this question here in hope it can be answered :)

Comment: Simple answer: You can't pass the Type directly, the compiler won't allow it. But you can go around it with implementations like the one above..It must be said that when developing code for industrial machines you should be aware of the special context you are in.Creating dynamic memory is used in the rarest occasions and should be avoided when not necessary. You have a very similar philosophy in the ADA language (83 or 95) widely used in military and civilian aviation.

Answer (score 1):

To my surprise (and by accident) I discovered that there is a file named `ETcloEcPredictDataType` containing this code:

```
{attribute 'TcTypeSystem'}
{attribute 'signature_flag' := '33554432'}
{attribute 'checksuperglobal'}
{attribute 'show'}
{attribute 'no-analysis'}

    {attribute 'GUID' := '6FFE9C73-9040-49AE-8731-5485B8A3A604'}
{attribute 'Namespace' := 'IO'}
TYPE ETcIoEcPredictDataType : (_SINT:=1, _USINT:=2, _INT:=3, _UINT:=4, _DINT:=5, _UDINT:=6, _LINT:=7, _ULINT:=8, _REAL:=9, _LREAL:=10) UDINT;
END_TYPE
```

> Note that I didn't even have to include this file. I just written down `_REAL` clicked on it and choose `Go to definition`. Then it opened the `ETcloEcPredictDataType` file.

---

So following to [@Filippo Boido](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65833985/11101156) answer you can create function with this `CASE` statement:

```
//_SINT:=1, _USINT:=2, _INT:=3, _UINT:=4, _DINT:=5, _UDINT:=6, _LINT:=7, _ULINT:=8, _REAL:=9, _LREAL:=10
CASE _type OF
    1: myArray := __NEW(SINT, size);
    2: myArray := __NEW(USINT, size);
    3: myArray := __NEW(INT, size);
    4: myArray := __NEW(UINT, size);
    5: myArray := __NEW(DINT, size);
    6: myArray := __NEW(UDINT, size);
    7: myArray := __NEW(LINT, size);
    8: myArray := __NEW(ULINT, size);
    9: myArray := __NEW(REAL, size);
    10: myArray := __NEW(LREAL, size);
END_CASE
```

And call the FB constructor as follows:

```
array : dynamicArray(_REAL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use ANY data type (or ANY_) for input variable. It will give you pointer to variable, its size and datatype (If you pass structure or fb, it will say just "USER_DEFINED". If you would like to compare datatype, use "IBaseLibrary.TypeClass" type.)

Also pay attention if you would like to pass the ANY variable into another function. ANY returns struct AnyType:

```
TYPE AnyType :
STRUCT
    // the type of the actual parameter
    typeclass : __SYSTEM.TYPE_CLASS ;
    // the pointer to the actual parameter
    pvalue : POINTER TO BYTE;
    // the size of the data, to which the pointer points
    diSize : DINT;
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE
```

...so that another function would have to accept variable of AnyType instead of ANY. ANY somehow works for compiler to know it should replace variable with filled AnyType struct.

see infosys https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/2529388939.html&id=

Answer (score 0):

PLC_ReadSymInfoByName() is a possibility to do this for Function Blocks,
attribute 'instance-path' > PLC_ReadSymInfoByName > "FB_Test"

it would also be Possible to do this with a Struct.
ST_Real: fValue: Real; eTypeOf : E_Type:= E_Type.Real;